# nats JetStream cluster consumer has NO quorum, stalled

Tags: go, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

We have 3 pods for nats, and the first one is constantly printing these logs:

```bash
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.774547 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_Z6YxJu8DajHFPJHexMQ5A9_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.812064 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_ZmHTX5PMtztBE5dZW5pYQA_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.817369 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_AnofbtWnJDuh9Yt27oeYDS_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.828555 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_MmwhUq5yJtJTwCSKF499yQ_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.832772 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_ukMX8maCu2dtkRKwndLyHi_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.897561 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_9pD8nToJz9QhL5vNBvQEMc_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.897964 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_5Uzpd7K7fHaotG2ZWyu7yP_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
[7] 2023/01/22 12:33:33.907856 [WRN] JetStream cluster consumer 'nbo > notification > Hermes_5ZoUda4k4pGLuhrGmAwYfN_notification' has NO quorum, stalled.
```

What is this log all about? and how can I fix it?

Our nats-server version is: 2.6.5

```bash
JetStream cluster consumer has NO quorum, stalled.
```

Hermes is our notification service which is a nats consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your nats server to 2.8.3+ (or upper) may work,

Also, it's recommended to have at least 4 CPUs and 8Gi for JetStream-enabled servers.

If you want to learn more, have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/issues/2737) and [this discussion](https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/discussions/3210).